# CSS - making a navigation bar but it goes out section

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I am learning coding on FreeCodeCamp and try to code my first portfolio website.

I was trying to create a navigation bar next to an image inside "header" section with following syntax, but it goes out of "header" section.

Please help to check where did I do wrong? Appreciated.

```css
  body{
      font-family: 'slabo 27px', Times new roman;
      background-color: #F2F2F2;
    }
    header{
      background-color: #010101;
      width: auto;
    }
    ul{
      list-style-type: none;
    }
    li{
      float: right;
    }
    a{
      display: block;
      padding: 8px;
      background-color: #010101;
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">

    <header>
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HilrPscVgt8SwodMthwXOsQWOmSbqFSbbM4rKSGnZa4WaMrrtIYfgbkWjNV6LwNjUgAX7GkI0jVcSTrR_Q4I9MZA_ymPje03V-npXDTIn7vr69BdU2Mh9zxFm8_egBTcVTg3_HZAqAk16CCFQExvZKENnmZQEsmrHeuigotSsLw8U24enecE5IM-ywRSg47qDiffMOnTUpywOIMv-asVgmjgGn9aXUL27SEQStkZ2RBY-cGGLDm8FP6IUEKrfizee-zN2O2xs3Y8UKZ-GbhyGYZuIOV_DRX7vXozvwfhN_IgQ0mKzrM0pAR-OxVJRLnJzZTSJhUyC6aayyxvX-UEdWt7o7pk_WkzgWleswlNLXw_KHrzR-Cf7yReZSnF1AOxTrn4V53Mgdp1m_yX9IvAAFqnMCBkUwMwvBppn7Sda6l3eN3nnRgS5Dw6NuYXCFilhpkZnDn_avB-Kz9jM5VFtbOs7z6rSWDqHIn9caHHX564ergfdlRHbHGRuXjX6Ey2kejbkhpnzmp0-N4dbX_DXC1yt1ZZY0r0gayFTAgk95acLpcJxb740iAvBbx2s7SzUi1C83gPMNMo4Vd-saG57syQMvT0rNwXIwcSPxH4Tcb7iW9iRWOueA=w542-h963-no", alt="my booooy" width="50px" style="margin-left: 50px">
        <ul>
          <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="description">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</div>
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HilrPscVgt8SwodMthwXOsQWOmSbqFSbbM4rKSGnZa4WaMrrtIYfgbkWjNV6LwNjUgAX7GkI0jVcSTrR_Q4I9MZA_ymPje03V-npXDTIn7vr69BdU2Mh9zxFm8_egBTcVTg3_HZAqAk16CCFQExvZKENnmZQEsmrHeuigotSsLw8U24enecE5IM-ywRSg47qDiffMOnTUpywOIMv-asVgmjgGn9aXUL27SEQStkZ2RBY-cGGLDm8FP6IUEKrfizee-zN2O2xs3Y8UKZ-GbhyGYZuIOV_DRX7vXozvwfhN_IgQ0mKzrM0pAR-OxVJRLnJzZTSJhUyC6aayyxvX-UEdWt7o7pk_WkzgWleswlNLXw_KHrzR-Cf7yReZSnF1AOxTrn4V53Mgdp1m_yX9IvAAFqnMCBkUwMwvBppn7Sda6l3eN3nnRgS5Dw6NuYXCFilhpkZnDn_avB-Kz9jM5VFtbOs7z6rSWDqHIn9caHHX564ergfdlRHbHGRuXjX6Ey2kejbkhpnzmp0-N4dbX_DXC1yt1ZZY0r0gayFTAgk95acLpcJxb740iAvBbx2s7SzUi1C83gPMNMo4Vd-saG57syQMvT0rNwXIwcSPxH4Tcb7iW9iRWOueA=w542-h963-no" class="col-md-4" width="50px" style="margin-left:10%">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio">
      <img src="">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contactme">
      <div></div>
      <img src="">
      <div>
        <form action="/submit contact data"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" required>
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        Want to get in touch with me? Be it to request more info about myself or my experience, to ask for my resume, tips on how to solve your sudoku, random questions about the universe and the meaning of life, or even if only for some nice Fika here in stunning Toronto... just feel free to drop me a line anytime.
    I promise to reply A.S.A.P.
      </div>
      <div class="bottomline">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="lastline" align="center">
        <p>Chun Hong © 2016. All Rights Reversed</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block;` on both `image` in `ul`

I changed background-color of your links to red for visibility in this example. I also added `float:right;` to your `ul`. it is not necessary but just to make it look good.

```css
body{
 font-family: 'slabo 27px', Times new roman;
 background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
header{
 background-color: #010101;
 width: auto;
}
header img{
 display:inline-block;
}
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline-block;
 float:right;
}
li{
 float: right;
}
a{
 display: block;
 padding: 8px;
 color:white;
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">

    <header>
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HilrPscVgt8SwodMthwXOsQWOmSbqFSbbM4rKSGnZa4WaMrrtIYfgbkWjNV6LwNjUgAX7GkI0jVcSTrR_Q4I9MZA_ymPje03V-npXDTIn7vr69BdU2Mh9zxFm8_egBTcVTg3_HZAqAk16CCFQExvZKENnmZQEsmrHeuigotSsLw8U24enecE5IM-ywRSg47qDiffMOnTUpywOIMv-asVgmjgGn9aXUL27SEQStkZ2RBY-cGGLDm8FP6IUEKrfizee-zN2O2xs3Y8UKZ-GbhyGYZuIOV_DRX7vXozvwfhN_IgQ0mKzrM0pAR-OxVJRLnJzZTSJhUyC6aayyxvX-UEdWt7o7pk_WkzgWleswlNLXw_KHrzR-Cf7yReZSnF1AOxTrn4V53Mgdp1m_yX9IvAAFqnMCBkUwMwvBppn7Sda6l3eN3nnRgS5Dw6NuYXCFilhpkZnDn_avB-Kz9jM5VFtbOs7z6rSWDqHIn9caHHX564ergfdlRHbHGRuXjX6Ey2kejbkhpnzmp0-N4dbX_DXC1yt1ZZY0r0gayFTAgk95acLpcJxb740iAvBbx2s7SzUi1C83gPMNMo4Vd-saG57syQMvT0rNwXIwcSPxH4Tcb7iW9iRWOueA=w542-h963-no", alt="my booooy" width="50px" style="margin-left: 50px">
        <ul>
          <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
          <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div id="description">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</div>
      <div></div>
      <div class="col-md-8">Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</div>
      <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HilrPscVgt8SwodMthwXOsQWOmSbqFSbbM4rKSGnZa4WaMrrtIYfgbkWjNV6LwNjUgAX7GkI0jVcSTrR_Q4I9MZA_ymPje03V-npXDTIn7vr69BdU2Mh9zxFm8_egBTcVTg3_HZAqAk16CCFQExvZKENnmZQEsmrHeuigotSsLw8U24enecE5IM-ywRSg47qDiffMOnTUpywOIMv-asVgmjgGn9aXUL27SEQStkZ2RBY-cGGLDm8FP6IUEKrfizee-zN2O2xs3Y8UKZ-GbhyGYZuIOV_DRX7vXozvwfhN_IgQ0mKzrM0pAR-OxVJRLnJzZTSJhUyC6aayyxvX-UEdWt7o7pk_WkzgWleswlNLXw_KHrzR-Cf7yReZSnF1AOxTrn4V53Mgdp1m_yX9IvAAFqnMCBkUwMwvBppn7Sda6l3eN3nnRgS5Dw6NuYXCFilhpkZnDn_avB-Kz9jM5VFtbOs7z6rSWDqHIn9caHHX564ergfdlRHbHGRuXjX6Ey2kejbkhpnzmp0-N4dbX_DXC1yt1ZZY0r0gayFTAgk95acLpcJxb740iAvBbx2s7SzUi1C83gPMNMo4Vd-saG57syQMvT0rNwXIwcSPxH4Tcb7iW9iRWOueA=w542-h963-no" class="col-md-4" width="50px" style="margin-left:10%">
    </div>
    <div class="portfolio">
      <img src="">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="contactme">
      <div></div>
      <img src="">
      <div>
        <form action="/submit contact data"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Message" required>
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        Want to get in touch with me? Be it to request more info about myself or my experience, to ask for my resume, tips on how to solve your sudoku, random questions about the universe and the meaning of life, or even if only for some nice Fika here in stunning Toronto... just feel free to drop me a line anytime.
    I promise to reply A.S.A.P.
      </div>
      <div class="bottomline">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="lastline" align="center">
        <p>Chun Hong © 2016. All Rights Reversed</p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is the effect I want. But I don't know why and how the effect comes out. Could you please advise where can I find the instruction of CSS syntax effect? Thank you.

Comment: It was happening because of `ul` element,because it was taking full width and could not fit in with the image. and it disappeared when I added `display:inline-block;` to it. Now I can't elaborate about `display` property here, since it's too broad. but here's a great article explaining it's basics:  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Comment: You should learn how to use developer tools in your browser. (they come up when you press f12). It will only take a few minutes (you can watch a youtube video) and they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You must set the max-width on the image to 100%.

```
header image{
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thx, but it is not the effect I want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for this.

Add `display: flex` to the header container, so all items inside will align in a row. Furthermore, you can also apply the same approach to the listing. Just add `display: flex` to the `ul` element and set the `align-items: center`, which will center your items vertically. The `flex-wrap: wrap` ensures that your items will wrap if there is not enough space for them in one line. To push your navigation items to the right, you can simply add `margin-left: auto` to your `ul` element

Finally I've also added `width: 100%` (instead of `auto`) to the `header` element.

Check out the snippet below

```css
body{
  font-family: 'slabo 27px', Times new roman;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
header{
  background-color: #010101;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  align-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header > img {
  height: 80px;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
}
a{
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #010101;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HilrPscVgt8SwodMthwXOsQWOmSbqFSbbM4rKSGnZa4WaMrrtIYfgbkWjNV6LwNjUgAX7GkI0jVcSTrR_Q4I9MZA_ymPje03V-npXDTIn7vr69BdU2Mh9zxFm8_egBTcVTg3_HZAqAk16CCFQExvZKENnmZQEsmrHeuigotSsLw8U24enecE5IM-ywRSg47qDiffMOnTUpywOIMv-asVgmjgGn9aXUL27SEQStkZ2RBY-cGGLDm8FP6IUEKrfizee-zN2O2xs3Y8UKZ-GbhyGYZuIOV_DRX7vXozvwfhN_IgQ0mKzrM0pAR-OxVJRLnJzZTSJhUyC6aayyxvX-UEdWt7o7pk_WkzgWleswlNLXw_KHrzR-Cf7yReZSnF1AOxTrn4V53Mgdp1m_yX9IvAAFqnMCBkUwMwvBppn7Sda6l3eN3nnRgS5Dw6NuYXCFilhpkZnDn_avB-Kz9jM5VFtbOs7z6rSWDqHIn9caHHX564ergfdlRHbHGRuXjX6Ey2kejbkhpnzmp0-N4dbX_DXC1yt1ZZY0r0gayFTAgk95acLpcJxb740iAvBbx2s7SzUi1C83gPMNMo4Vd-saG57syQMvT0rNwXIwcSPxH4Tcb7iW9iRWOueA=w542-h963-no", alt="my booooy" width="50px" style="margin-left: 50px">
    <ul>
      <li><a>ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
      <li><a>CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
<div id="description">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">Front-End Developer and UX/UI designer, with practical experience in project management, branding strategy, and creative direction; devoted to functional programming and information architecture.</div>
  <div></div>
  <div class="col-md-8">Web Developer - User Experience Designer - Graphic Artist</div>
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HilrPscVgt8SwodMthwXOsQWOmSbqFSbbM4rKSGnZa4WaMrrtIYfgbkWjNV6LwNjUgAX7GkI0jVcSTrR_Q4I9MZA_ymPje03V-npXDTIn7vr69BdU2Mh9zxFm8_egBTcVTg3_HZAqAk16CCFQExvZKENnmZQEsmrHeuigotSsLw8U24enecE5IM-ywRSg47qDiffMOnTUpywOIMv-asVgmjgGn9aXUL27SEQStkZ2RBY-cGGLDm8FP6IUEKrfizee-zN2O2xs3Y8UKZ-GbhyGYZuIOV_DRX7vXozvwfhN_IgQ0mKzrM0pAR-OxVJRLnJzZTSJhUyC6aayyxvX-UEdWt7o7pk_WkzgWleswlNLXw_KHrzR-Cf7yReZSnF1AOxTrn4V53Mgdp1m_yX9IvAAFqnMCBkUwMwvBppn7Sda6l3eN3nnRgS5Dw6NuYXCFilhpkZnDn_avB-Kz9jM5VFtbOs7z6rSWDqHIn9caHHX564ergfdlRHbHGRuXjX6Ey2kejbkhpnzmp0-N4dbX_DXC1yt1ZZY0r0gayFTAgk95acLpcJxb740iAvBbx2s7SzUi1C83gPMNMo4Vd-saG57syQMvT0rNwXIwcSPxH4Tcb7iW9iRWOueA=w542-h963-no" class="col-md-4" width="50px" style="margin-left:10%">
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
  <img src="">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="contactme">
  <div></div>
  <img src="">
  <div>
    <form action="/submit contact data"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email address" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Message" required>
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    Want to get in touch with me? Be it to request more info about myself or my experience, to ask for my resume, tips on how to solve your sudoku, random questions about the universe and the meaning of life, or even if only for some nice Fika here in stunning Toronto... just feel free to drop me a line anytime.
I promise to reply A.S.A.P.
  </div>
  <div class="bottomline">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="lastline" align="center">
    <p>Chun Hong © 2016. All Rights Reversed</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Ramis Wachtler, your answer is quite good. I'll take a note of it, and keep learning these fundamentals.